# views_embed_view in computed field

Tags: views, entities

I have Content type A with these fields: Category and Amount. I want to add another field (Tax Amount) to calculate an amount based on Category and Amount inputted by user and sum of amount field of previously saved nodes.

In Tax Field, I used Computed Filed and trying to get sum of previously saved nodes by using two views, with category argument. Two views are 1) aggregated Amount of all previously saved nodes 2) aggregated Tax Amount of all previously saved nodes. Code I used inside computed field is below. But views_embed_view does not work I guess:

```
$arg = $fields['field_category'][0]['value'];
$amount = $fields['field_amount'][0]['value'];
$sum_nodes_amount = views_embed_view('views_machinename', 'block_1', $arg);
$sum_nodes_tax = views_embed_view('views_machinename', 'block_2', $arg);

$result = if ($amount + sum_nodes_amount) > 10,0000 {
print ($amount + $sum_nodes) * 20%
}

if ($amount + sum_nodes_amount) > 20,0000 {
print ($amount + $sum_nodes_amount) * 10%
}
else {
Print ($amount + $sum_nodes_amount) + $sum_nodes_tax * 1%

}

$value = $result;
```

Comment: The code contains syntax errors, starting from *PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) on line 6*. The other errors are the missing *$* in `$amount + sum_nodes_amount`, the missing instruction terminator (`;`) in some lines, and the missing second operator in `20%`, as in PHP the `%` is the remainder operator. (`echo 32 % 17;` prints 15.)

Comment: Instead of creating a new question, you should have edited the existing question. The new question isn't much better than the original one: There isn't an explicit question, and the code shown in the question contains basic syntax errors for which an explanation is off-topic for this site.

Comment: views_embed_view is not returning any result. I tried without if logic. In your opinion is it okay the way I write views_embed_view to get a views in a field?

Comment: `views_embed_view()` is not for getting field values; it embeds the whole view-- the theme template gets processed and you get a chunk of HTML. I would look for another way to get the tax info. (How does Views find the tax info?  Is it Commerce or some other module?  If so, you can pull the tax info from the same source that the Views module does and then you will have a clean value.)

Comment: @PatrickKenny Yes views_embed_view() was showing html as output " <div class="views-element-container"><div class="view view-dashboard-invoice-summary view-id-dashboard_invoice_summary view-display-id-block_6 js-view-dom-id-3b4a6932fc156a051a4b492016fc74b2d0a133cc4e9ab607d9964fd5760bbbb7">
<div cla " Tax field will be computed filed (integer) where I will calculate tax amount based on previous data (sum of all saved nodes) by embed view or other working functions. If views not returning number then I can't use "if" to get what I am looking for.

Comment: It's not a matter of using an `if` statement; it's that `$result = if ($amount + sum_nodes_amount) > 10,0000 { print ($amount + $sum_nodes_amount) * 10% }` isn't PHP code. The purpose of this site isn't teaching PHP, but how to correctly use the Drupal API. In a question about code, the code must be perfectly valid PHP code, or the question is off-topic for us, especially when the question is asking how to fix the code, or it's wondering why the code doesn't work.